# Visualizing GeoHashed data as polygons on QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, vector, choropleth, geohash

I have a .csv delimited text layer that includes a particular precision 7 geohash along with a certain measured value for the area represented by said geohash.

For example:

```
tc0fh3s,-101.0
tc0fxfg,-100.79
tc0fxfm,-97.75
```

I'm a bit lost on how I can visualize the geohashed data as a polygon layer on qgis. My final objective is to generate a choropleth map.

Comment: Do you have postgis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I resorted to doing was using the **Fields to point layer** function in the **[Lat Lon Tools](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/latlontools/)** plugin to get the points for the centroids of each geohash.

Next, I used the **[Rectangles, ovals, diamonds](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html?highlight=rectangles#rectangles-ovals-diamonds)** tool and generated rectangles using the dimensions mentioned [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-geohashgrid-aggregation.html).

This gave me the desired visualization.

Answer (score 2):

If you are ok with some postgis you can use [ST_GeomFromGeoHash](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromGeoHash.html) like this:

First add the csv file to QGIS using the Browser, drag and drop it to PostGIS and:

```
create table public.geohash_polygons as
select *, st_setsrid(st_geomfromgeohash(field_1), 4326) geom
from public.geohash
```

[image]